# In Latex, how to put two separate tables side by side on top of the paper?

Tags: latex

In Latex, how do I put two separate tables (with separate captains) side by side on top of a paper?

Any helps are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

One possibility is to align the table environment with `[t]` and split it using minipages, optionally separated by a flexible space.

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\hfillx{\hspace*{-\textwidth}\hfill}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[t]
        \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}{r | c c c}
                $+$
                  & 1 & 2 & 3 \\\hline
                1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
                2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
                3 & 4 & 5 & 6
            \end{tabular}
            \caption{Addition}
        \end{minipage}%
        \hfillx
        \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}{r | c c c}
                $\times$
                  & 1 & 2 & 3 \\\hline
                1 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
                2 & 2 & 4 & 6 \\
                3 & 3 & 6 & 9
            \end{tabular}
            \caption{Multiplication}
        \end{minipage}%
    \end{table}
    %
    \section{Section}
    
    Text
\end{document}
```

If the tables are big, it may be necessary to enlarge the upper fraction of the page in which floats are allowed by putting this into the preamble:

```
\def\textfraction{0.1}
\def\topfraction{0.9}
```